# Marketplace con React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Me dirijo a ustedes por una pregunta técnica que tengo. Estoy desarrollando un marketplace con React.js como biblioteca para el front-end. Estoy solo en este proyecto y estoy a cargo de la parte técnica del marketplace.

¿Qué tecnologías y buenas prácticas debo considerar para tener una aplicación confiable y segura? Además, ¿qué tipo de servidor debo considerar para instalar mi aplicación en producción?

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

por lo general las tecnologías y librerías de terceros que se usan junto con react son:

- Redux
- Redux-saga o Redux-thunk
- JWT para la autenticación si es necesaria
- Librerías de UI como MaterialUI o Bootstrap

Claro que el uso de las mismas dependerá de los requisitos de tu aplicación pero si es un marketplace debes manejar estados, sesiones y éstas tecnologías te ayudarán.

Para el servidor podrías utilizar uno que renderize contenido estático siempre y cuando no uses Server side rendering, yo te recomendaria usar ngnix.

La seguridad no es solo de tu aplicacion tambien debes pensar en la seguridad del servidor que aloja la app, no expongas tus variables y tokens al público. Aqui te dejo un enlace de buenas practicas para react https://upplabs.com/blog/react-js-security-best-practices/

Comment: Entendido! mil gracias por tu respuesta!